# Discord.js TypeScript: property run in type Command is not assignable to the same base property of BaseCommand

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

So, I am trying to do a command and since yesterday worked fine,
but today working on the command lead to this typescript error:

```
Property 'run' in type 'PredictCommand' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseCommand'.
  Type '(client: DiscordClient, message: Message, args: string[]) => Promise<Message>' is not assignable to type '(client: DiscordClient, message: Message, args: string[]) => Promise<void>'.
    Type 'Promise<Message>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<void>'.
      Type 'Message' is not assignable to type 'void'.
```

If you want to see the full code, here below there is the BaseCommand module and the code snippet in which I expanded the module:

```js
import { Message, MessageEmbed } from "discord.js";
import BaseCommand from "../../utils/structures/BaseCommand";
import DiscordClient from "../../client/client";

export default class PredictCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super("Predict", "fun", ["predict", "pred"]);
  }

  async run(client: DiscordClient, message: Message, args: Array<string>) {
    var Predictions = [
      "you will die of terminal dankness",
      "you will have a lovely gf ❤",
      "you will receive free money from Mr. Beast",
      "Shrek will bless you with his greatness",
      "yOu ArE tHe ImPoStOR! I sEe yOu WiLl VeNt!",
      "you will live a wonderful life ",
      "you will be chosen for exploring Antartica",
      "you will be considered a city hero",
      "you will be healthy and you will grow as a perfect Shrekling",
      "you.. no sorry the dev will run out of ideas ... that's why you should do `s!predictsuggest <description>` in chat!",
      "Obi-Wan will take you as his apprendice",
    ];
    switch (args[1]) {
      case "add":
        if (!args[2]) {
          return message.channel.send(
            "Sorry, but for adding a predict you need to write `s!predict add <your predict>`. To see how to make a good predict run `s!predict help`"
          );
        }
        var newpredict = args[2];
        Predictions.push(newpredict);
        break;
      case "viewall":
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
          return message.channel.send(
            "You dummy, you can't see into Shrek's mind!"
          );
        }
        let viewemb = new MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("Predictions: admin panel")
          .setDescription(
            `Here there are all my predictions for now: ${Predictions}, with a total of ${Predictions.length}`
          )
          .setColor(0xa3ae7e);
        message.member.send(viewemb);
        break;
      case "help":
        let helpemb = new MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor("Predictions: help page")
          .setDescription(
            `The predict command lets Shrek see into your future and give a verdict. Just do ${client.prefix}predict !`
          )
          .addField(
            "Prediction suggestions",
            `If you want to suggest a predict Shrek will say, just do ${client.prefix}predict add <description>. \n To make a good command follow these guidelines: \n • Start the predict with "you will..." \n • Don't put offensive content on the predict \n • Don't exceed the 80 caracters limit`
          )
          .setColor(0xa3ae7e)
          .setFooter(`${message.author.tag}`);
        message.channel.send(helpemb);
    }
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor("`Shrek predicts your future`")
      .setDescription(
        ` Hold up a second ${message.author}, Shrek is looking in your future...`
      )
      .setColor(0xa3ae7e);
    message.channel.send(embed);
    const chosenpredit =
      Predictions.find[Math.floor(Math.random() * Predictions.length)];
    let nextembed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor("Shrek predicted your future!")
      .setDescription(`In your future... ${chosenpredit}`)
      .setColor(0xa3ae7e);
    message.channel.send(nextembed);
  }
}
```

Here below the basecommand module:

```
import { Message } from 'discord.js';
import DiscordClient from '../../client/client';

export default abstract class BaseCommand {
  constructor(private name: string, private category: string, private aliases: Array<string>) {}

  getName(): string { return this.name; }
  getCategory(): string { return this.category; }
  getAliases(): Array<string> { return this.aliases; }

  abstract async run(client: DiscordClient, message: Message, args: Array<string> | null): Promise<void>;
}
```

**Can someone be able to answer it?**

Answer (score 2):

In your base command change
`Promise<void>`
to
`Promise<any>`
And if you have discord then join the Discord.js community there really helpful!!